# Choose best mobile web framework that works for wordpress

Tags: css, html, web-applications, frameworks

I want to build an web app for wordpress which has a theme that I design.

I have already learned html5 and css3.
Which framework would you suggest on me and how can I design the app from scratch ?
and I have an extra request if somebody will answer , can you link your social networking account please , thanks

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise Omar.

Comment: thanks for your note

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out **Twitter Bootstrap** - http://getbootstrap.com and **Zurb Foundation** - http://foundation.zurb.com. These two are the most popular mobile responsive frameworks out right now. If you want lighter alternatives which are not as bloated, you can check out **Skeleton** - http://getskeleton.com

Comment: Thanks bro you made my day

Answer (score 0):

Here are a two mobile frameworks that seem pretty simple to use

**Bootstrap** - click [here](http://getbootstrap.com/)

**Kendo UI** - click [here](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui)

Comment: Thx bro you are the coolest